# Sticky Group Headers in ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, sticky

I am binding a WPF ListBox to a ICollectionView which is grouped. The ListBox displays correctly with the group headers, but I want to add additional behavior to this.

I want group headers to stick to the top until the next group header causes it to slide out of view.  This is similar to how the IPhone contact list works where the headers, 'A', B', 'C', stick to the top until the next letter category replaces it.

[image: Illustration]

I thought this would be a popular feature, but I am not able to find an example of this online.

Answer (score 1):

Very old question but here is how I would have handled your requirement (showing "Sticky Group Headers" for a ListBox/List view in WPF).

1. ListView already provides this feature. Check if your ControlTemplate is properly written.

If you are using a ListBox,

1. Get the adorned layer of the ListBox.
2. Show the group title in this adorned layer based on scroll bar position.

Answer (score 0):

What you might be describing here is an `Accordion` control.

[image]

Please check WPFToolkit for the same. http://wpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/40535

Comment: Created a picture illustrating what I am trying to accomplish. [link](http://flic.kr/p/bcbnNM)  I hope this helps in being more clear.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: With a little tweaking of the accordion control, you can achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I just implemented this using [this example](http://www.japf.fr/2010/11/a-wpf-behavior-to-improve-grouping-in-your-listbox/comment-page-1/), which is a nice Behavior that can be attached to the ListBox.

There is one small bug where the header is not on top in the original article. That is fixed [here](https://github.com/RSchwoerer/code-examples/tree/master/ListBoxAnimatedGroup).